# Bigcommerce - How to request Authorization Code/Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

In my application, the user when installs the app, needs to fill a registration form. I need to save the access_token along with the user instance.

So, if the user is unregistered, I redirect to the signup form ie. I dont save the access_token, but at this time, the app is registered. Which means, suppose when the store admin logs back in to the app, he does not get the auth code again, but gets signed_payload.

Since, I dont want to store, unregistered users on my database, I prefer calling a api, that would grant me auth code and/or access_token.

Is there any such call I can make?

Comment: In BigCommerce, when the app is installed for the very first time, BC makes a GET request to whatever URL you've specified as being the initial install program (you define this URL yourself in the BC developer dashboard). Your initial install program should contain the logic to retrieve the access token and prompt for user registration. This access token is permanent, so you need to save it on your side.

Comment: Additionally, you also set a separate URL for the `app load`, this is the URL that BC will call whenever the user opens your app *AFTER* it has already been installed. This URL should point to the program that verifies the signed_payload and retrieves the user's access_token from your database.

Comment: If the user installs your app, and then exists before completing your registration, then you will have a valid access_token for the store, but the user is not completely registered on your end. In this case, your `app load` code should simply check if the registration fields exist in your database, if they do not, then that means the user did not fill it out, and so your program should show the registration page (while still using the same access_token you got when the app was first installed), and wait until registration is completed before showing your main app dashboard.Hope this make cents

Comment: Summary: Saving the access token should be the first thing you always do. User registration should be a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a programming language, I'm going to illustrate one in Python.

There are two parts you mentioned, registration/access token and signed payload.

The **initial callback flow** would look something like this:

```py
@app.route('/bigcommerce/callback')
def auth_callback():
    # Put together params for token request
    code = flask.request.args['code']
    context = flask.request.args['context']
    scope = flask.request.args['scope']
    store_hash = context.split('/')[1]
    redirect = app.config['APP_URL'] + flask.url_for('auth_callback')

    # Fetch a permanent oauth token. This will throw an exception on error,
    # which will get caught by our error handler above.
    client = BigcommerceApi(client_id=client_id(), store_hash=store_hash)
    token = client.oauth_fetch_token(client_secret(), code, context, scope, redirect)
    bc_user_id = token['user']['id']
    email = token['user']['email']
    access_token = token['access_token']
```

The flow using a **signed payload** would look something like:

```py
@app.route('/bigcommerce/load')
def load():
    # Decode and verify payload
    payload = flask.request.args['signed_payload']
    user_data = BigcommerceApi.oauth_verify_payload(payload, client_secret())
    if user_data is False:
        return "Payload verification failed!", 401

    bc_user_id = user_data['user']['id']
    email = user_data['user']['email']
    store_hash = user_data['store_hash']
```

When initially creating a user in your database, you can also denote the sign up date through a function of your code and then do a periodic cron job to check if they have a registered account with you. There's not an endpoint where we store whether they completed registration with you since that is a function of your app.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the access token can only be obtained at the point of the initial app install, when the user installs the app for the very first time. This is the only time that BigCommerce will send the information required to obtain the access token.

Therefore your app should always save the access_token at the point of install. Your registration page should be prompted after obtaining and saving the access token. If for some reason the user installs the app and does not complete the registration, then you should simply just check on your end if the registration was finished or not, and if it wasn't then you should display it during the `app load` phase as a requirement before displaying your main app dashboard.